# css box-shadow for table row?

Tags: html, css

Here is my HTML code:

```html
<style>
.yellow{
    background-color: yellow;
}
td{
    width:40px;
}
tr:first-child {
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 5px #d99292;
}
</style>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class=yellow>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td class=yellow>4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The goal is to have a drop shadow around the first row. The problem is that the background color of cell 4 is obscuring it.

My question is: how do I make the drop show show on top of the background of cell 4?

edit: see follow-up question: [css inset box-shadow for table row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64510914/css-inset-box-shadow-for-table-row)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lower the z-index of the next cells:

```css
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

td {
  width: 40px;
}

tr:first-child {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 5px #d99292;
}

tr:first-child  + tr td {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}

/* the below is not mandatory but to make sure 
the cells doesn't go below the table */
table {
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class=yellow>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td class=yellow>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```