# css inset box-shadow for table row?

Tags: html, css

see my related yet different  question: [css box-shadow for table row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64342001/css-box-shadow-for-table-row)

Here is my HTML code:

```html
<style>
.yellow{
    background-color: yellow;
}
td{
    width:40px;
}
tr:first-child {
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 5px 5px #d99292;
}
</style>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class=yellow>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td class=yellow>4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The goal is to have a inset drop shadow in the first row. The problem is that the background color of cell 1 is obscuring it.

My question is: how do I make the inset drop show show on top of the background of cell 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also give a try to [`mix-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode)

> The `mix-blend-mode` CSS property sets how an element's content should blend with the content of the element's parent and the element's background.

```css
.yellow{
    background-color: yellow;
    mix-blend-mode:multiply
}
td{
    width:40px;
}
tr:first-child {
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 5px 5px #d99292;
 /*optionnal :
    background:white ; 
  to avoid .yellow mixing eventually with body, or else background */
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class=yellow>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td class=yellow>4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks! this is the simplest answer and works rather nicely including in my much more complex project

Answer (score 2):

color the table cell using a pseudo element that you can make behind the shadow:

```css
table {
  position:relative;
  z-index:-1;
}

.yellow {
  position:relative;
}
.yellow::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:yellow;
}

td {
  width: 40px;
}

tr:first-child {
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 5px 5px #d99292;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class=yellow>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td class=yellow>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a work round here.

Adding an absolute empty `tr` to be on the top.

```css
.yellow{
    background-color: yellow;
}
td{
    width:40px;
}
tr:first-child {
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 5px 5px #d99292;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class=yellow>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td class=yellow>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: making tr display:flex will break the table layout (https://jsfiddle.net/9gjcm2rz/)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks for point out it. Although it works in this scenario because the td has a width set, I'll update the answer to remove that solution.